# Apply attribute class to Python class which Inherits a C# base Class

Tags: c#, python, attributes, ironpython

I have a base class in C# which is like so

```
   Class A
   {
     public ClassA()
     { 

     }

     .....
   }
```

In python I Inherit this base class

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("MyClass.dll")
from MyNamespace import ClassA    

class MySubclass(ClassA):
    def _init_(self):
        print "I'm in a subclass in python"
```

I also have an attribute class in C# called `MyAttrib("Value")`

Somewhere later on in my C# code I check that any classes derived from `ClassA` have the Attribute `MyAttrib` applied to it, which fails in the case of the Python class.

Is there a way to do either of the following :

1. Apply an attrib class to the derived class in Python?
2. Set the AttributeValue in Python somehow when the object is being instantiated?
3. Some other, way to do what I am thinking about

I am using IronPython with plug-ins for Visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a simple way to do that. It's definitely easier to use a C# stub class having the necessary attributes defined and subclass that.

But, if you ***really*** need to define a class like that in python, you can use a workaround (as shown [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dynamically_compiling.shtml) )

Basically you can compile (in memory) a piece of C# code and import that in IronPython. Given that is a C# piece of code you can add attributes and hence your problem is solved.

This is of course quite convoluted because your basically embedding a language into another making a chain like this: `C# <- IronPython <- C#`, then, again, I'd strongly suggest you to define a C# class already having the necessary attributes and use that.